# How can you send an email to another users email without opening the mail? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building an app in Xamarin Forms where you can buy products etc. Now I am at the stage where I want to send the user a confirmation when their order has been placed.

I have a string cointaining their email but I am not quite sure how to proceed. When I have previously worked with mail it looks something like this:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:ryan.hatfield@test.com?subject=free candy&body=you can trust me"));
```

And what this does is that you open your own mail and you have to send it yourself to yourself which obviously is wrong.

So my question is, how can I send a confirmation email from my email to their inputted email which I have stored in a string?

Comment: Your *server* needs to send the confirmation mail to the user, not the user's device.

Comment: Ah ok, so in my case I have to do it via my PHP-backend then.

Comment: Yes.  Your backend is the one who actually handles the order, so it should send the confirmation.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will look into it or maybe use the Exchange Web Services (EWS) depends on what is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. If your email is a Microsoft Exchange mailbox, you can use Exchange Web Services (EWS), which is fairly simple if you follow code samples online. Otherwise, you should use an SMTP client. .NET has its own that you can include: `System.Net.Mail`, or you can find a number of libraries online.

If you're inclined toward the .NET SMTP option, I would take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537339/how-to-send-mails-using-smtpclient-and-defaultnetworkcredentials-to-a-distributi). It has a fairly complete example that should help you get started.

EDIT: You mentioned that your backend is PHP-Based. There are plenty of SMTP libraries for PHP as well and plenty of code samples. Here's another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server) I'd suggest you look at to help you get started in PHP instead of C#.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it

Comment: Just an FYI, if you want to use Exchange Web Services in PHP, I'm maintaining a fairly decent (In my opinion) library to do that. Here's the library. http://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/